# PHP: How can this code be fixed to work correctly?

Tags: php, php-5.3

Consider the following code:

```
$str1 = 'yahoo';
$str2 = 'google';
if (strpos($str1,$str2)) {
    echo "\"" . $str1 . "\" contains \"" . $str2 . "\"";
} else {
    echo "\"" . $str1 . "\" does not contain \"" . $str2 . "\"";
}
```

The output will be:

"yahoo" does not contain "google" , Why? How can this code be fixed to work correctly?

Trying to understand the first question of this [link](https://www.toptal.com/php/interview-questions)

Comment: Well and what are you expecting? in string "yahoo" there is no substring "google".

Comment: It works correctly. Define what do you mean by "work correctly". What is your expected outcome?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Those examples are different though. Same code, but different strings. To know the answer of that "interview question", see the warning and examples in the manual of this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php - the manual is always the first place you should look at if you have any questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, you got wrong example of words.

If you have words "yababababa" and "yaba" its different.
Strpos returns position of substring in string, so if substring begins on the begining of the parent word, it returns 0, which in simple condition `if (strpos($str1,$str2)` means false, and it say there is no "yaba" in "yababababa".

You have to also check type of return value from strpos - it have to be boolean false/true.

`if (strpos($str1,$str2) !== false)`

Comment: Got it .Thanks. :)